# Label will not stick to right side of LabelFrame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a `LabelFrame` using `ttk` from `tkinter`. I currently have 3 columns of labels in the `LabelFrame`. The first 2 columns align to the right but I want the third column to stick to the right side of the frame.

Here is my current code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()

seeds = [1, 16]
teams = ["First Team", "Some Other Team"]
scores = [148, 6]

def make_game(seeds = ["", ""], teams = ["", ""], scores = ["", ""], game_name = "Game!", r=0, c=0):
    game = ttk.LabelFrame(window, text=game_name)
    game.grid(row = r, column=c, pady=5, padx=5, sticky=tk.EW)
    
    game_top_seed = ttk.Label(game, text=str(seeds[0]))
    game_top_seed.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky=tk.W)
    game_bot_seed = ttk.Label(game, text=str(seeds[1]))
    game_bot_seed.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky=tk.W)
    game_top_team = ttk.Label(game, text=teams[0])
    game_top_team.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
    game_bot_team = ttk.Label(game, text=teams[1])
    game_bot_team.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.W)
    game_top_score = ttk.Label(game, text=str(scores[0]), anchor=tk.E)
    game_top_score.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E)
    game_bot_score = ttk.Label(game, text=str(scores[1]), anchor=tk.E)
    game_bot_score.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E)

make_game(seeds=[1, 16], teams=['Alabama', 'Other'], scores=[85, 72], game_name="South Game 1", r=0, c=0)
make_game(seeds, teams, scores, game_name="South Game 2", r=1, c=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Here is what this gives me. I want the scores to stay along the right side of the box for each game.

[image: What I get]

I have tried anchoring the score labels using `anchor=tk.E` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the third column to use all the available space by calling:

```
game.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
```

and the result:

[image]